# How do I set a session to expire within 4 minutes?

Tags: python, django, http, session, count

Suppose I do this:

```
request.session['x'] = 33
```

How do I make this session variable expire in 4 minutes? This variable only!! I don't want all the sessions to expire.

If this cannot be done, is there a function that can keep track of it? (a function that uses sessions itself to count?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to track the age of session variable yourself. In actual Python code it could look something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

request.session['x'] = dict(dt=datetime.now(), value='something')

MAX_AGE = timedelta(seconds=240)

if ('x' in request.session and datetime.now() - request.session['x']['dt'] > MAX_AGE):
    del request.session['x']
```

It may also be possible to store your value in the cookie depending on what data it is and size.

Answer (score 1):

You can't expire a single variable within the session automatically.

Instead, you could store that variable in its own cookie, for which you can set a four-minute expiry. See the [documentation on how to set cookies](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie).

Answer (score 0):

```
request.session['x_settime'] = time x was set
if (request.session['x_settime'] is older than 4 minutes) {
     delete request.session['x']
     delete request.session['x_settime']
}
```

p.s. this is not python